# UI-Router 1.X - how to handle exceptions thrown from resolve functions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

#### Exception in resolve function while transitioning to a new state in angularjs

I've a code to transition to new state on a button click, but one of the resolve functions is failing due to some error at the server. How and where should I handle this exception. I've tried the method described in this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1783, but it didn't help. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right or not. This is what my code looks like after taking it from the link, upon setting a break point and debug my code but I don't see the break point hitting on exception from the resolve function. Please correct me what am I doing wrong here or guide me in the right direction to get this resolved.

```
window.app = angular.module('app', ['di'])

app.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        if(toState.name == 'Categories')
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    });
}])
```

Route setting code

```
{
    name: 'app.setting',
    url: '/settings',
    abstract: true,
    component: 'settingDetails',
    resolve: {
        getData: ($stateParams,
        $http)=>$stateParams.locationGroupId?$http.get(`/ui/getData/${
            $stateParams.id
        }/`).then(response=>response.data): [],
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear what the question is.  Are you asking why you aren't entering into the $stateChangeError watcher's callback when setting a break point?  Or are you asking how you should handle the server error?

Comment: Are you using UI-router V0.X or V1.X? Also show the code for the resolve function.

Comment: My question is how to handle the exceptions that were thrown from the resolve functions. I've followed the code in the link, which is not working for me. If it is working it would have hit my break point.

Comment: @georgeawg, this is my ui router version 1.0.0-rc.1. If you mean that code for resolve function is how I'm calling that...I've added it to my question.

Comment: With UI-Router 1.X, state change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by Transition Hooks. Instead of listening for events, use the Transition Hook API. See [UI-Router Guide - 1.0 Migration - State Change Events](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events)

Answer (score 1):

> my ui router version 1.0.0-rc.1.

With UI-Router 1.X, state change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by Transition Hooks. Instead of listening for events, use the Transition Hook API.

For more information, see [UI-Router Guide - 1.0 Migration - State Change Events](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events)